# How to make conky appear on top of all windows?

Tags: gnome, configuration, manjaro, window, conky

How to make a conky window on top of all windows?
The only thing i find is how to avoid it but i want conky to be on top of all windows. 
I would like to know what parameter is responsible for this or what is the crutch to do this?

I use Manjaro,
Gnome 43.5m
WM: Mutter
I would like to achieve this with built-in tools, but knowing Linux, you can install another 100500 packages.